# (Google Play) App dropped to rock bottom in multiple countries / top-lists after simple metadata change in a single country

Tags: google-play

**Background info:** Our game has been pretty stable for months in the top 100 roleplay category in over 55 countries while we've been hovering in the top 10 in around 5-8 countries.

**Problem:** After some metadata change (minor title & short description adjustments) in a few countries we've been immediately dropping like 100-400 positions in ***all*** countries (whether the country was involved in the metadata changes or not). We couldn't believe our eyes and were not able to wrap our head around how a ‘short description’ change in Poland can make us drop from #70 to #416 in the US-Roleplay charts. We dug through our data and we were able to find another similar occurrence. In June last year we exclusively changed the title of our game in France and immediately dropped 3x our ranking in 20 or more countries as well. In June all positions recovered over the timespan of 8 days, unfortunately it seems like this time this is not the case.

We’re aware of the importance of keywords and the impact metadata can have. We still rank very good on all our important keywords and the traffic coming from play store searches haven’t really changed as well.

Have any of you ever experienced this? What information are we missing? Looking forward to hearing your thoughts. Needless to say, we appreciate all input :)

Answer (score 0):

We also faced something similar during the same time as you posted this message. To confirm, is your app title longer than 30 characters (do check all listings)? Google might have started to penalize for that. We are also figuring the same.
No luck with recovering the ranks

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I can confirm all app titles are below 30 characters and shortdescriptions are cover all new requirements as well. We've made the required changes to be in line with the new guidelines weeks before the occurance (with no negative impact). Right now, we have at least some of our rankings back with the help of buying traffic. However it seems like we can not hold them without financial power. Before the incident we've been stable on these ranks for month.

Comment: If you want to talk about the issue in a private conversation/chat let me know and i'll provide contact information in my profile.